# How to "save" svg symbols when transforming a map in QGIS using qgis2web to create a web map?

Tags: qgis, svg, qgis2web

I'm very new to QGIS so might be getting the terminology wrong.

I created a map with several layers in QGIS. I needed different markers than the ones provided so I used svg markers. Now I'd like to use qgis2web to create a web map - when I do so, my svg markers don't show up but only the Labels which I've also put.

How can I fix this so that the svg markers show up in the web map?

Comment: This sounds like a qgis2web bug, so can you open an issue at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/?

Comment: If you are using leaflet, this is explained in this tutorial: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html